# Middleware Plugin in WCF

Tags: wcf, middleware

How to create event notification web service or kind of middleware in WCF? Any good links or books there to start? Or do we have any open source light weight open source middle ware projects?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want? Lack of clarity is probably why this has only one answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at NServiceBus: http://www.nservicebus.com/

Here's an article about it: http://www.udidahan.com/2009/02/07/nservicebus-19/

Answer (score 0):

This could be used for event notification
http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx